# How to get category wise all product without one specific product ID in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a category table, product table.I want to show category wise all products except one specific product id which comes from request

Here is the model relationship

**Product Model**

```
public function category(){
   return $this>belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

**CategoryModel**

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

I'm getting all products by this way

```
    $product = Product::findOrFail(10);
    $category_products = $product ->category->products;
```

But I want to get all products except  product_id 10. How can I get that?

Comment: Is there a many to many relation between category and product ? what is the purpose of pivot table? If there is m:m relation so what if product 10 belongs to multiple categories  and these categories may share duplicate products? Can you post your model definitions

Comment: I've edited my post, please check again, there is no pivot table for this

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain eager relations with the `with()` method, passing a closure.

```
$id = 10;

$product = Product::findOrFail($id)
    ->with(['category.products' => fn ($query) => $query->where('id', '!=', $id)])
    ->get();

$otherProducts = $product->category->products;
```

pre php 7.4

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id)
    ->with(['category.products' => function ($query) use ($id) {
        return $query->where('id', '!=', $id);
    }])
    ->get();
```

on second thoughts, a more efficient way might be to just query the products table directly:

```
$otherProducts = Product::query()
    ->where('category_id', $categoryId)
    ->where('id', '!=', $productId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Your code gives an error "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'
"

Comment: ah you're probably on an old php version then? I've added in the version with pre 7.4 syntax

Comment: I get nothing from your pre  7.4 syntax code

Comment: I made a couple of edits, but note this website is best used to have someone point you in the right direction, not to write your solution character by character.

Answer (score 0):

To show category wise products and exclude specific products from related collection you can query category of product and eager load related products using `with` but remove your desired product from collection using a closure method

```
$product = 10;
$category = Category::with(['products'=> function($query) use($product)  {
                $query->where('id','!=', $prodcut);
            }])
            ->whereHas('products', function (Builder $query) use($product) {
                $query->where('id', $product);
            })->get();
```